# How to test 3.5" screen layouts in Xcode 8?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios-simulator

Xcode 8 removes the iPhone 4 and 4s simulators, leaving no devices with 3.5" screens. However, Apple still requires compatibility with 3.5" devices, and just rejected one of my apps because some graphical elements were misaligned on 3.5" screens. I no longer own a 3.5" iPhone. How can I test my app on a 3.5" screen to pass this review?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to test the 3.5" experience with Xcode 8, you will need to test on an iPhone 4s simulator device.  Such devices do not support iOS 10 (which is what comes with Xcode 8).  You will need to install an older iOS Simulator Runtime from Xcode's Preferences (in the Components tab) and of course set your project's deployment target accordingly.

Comment: Oh, you're right. I already had the iOS 9 runtime installed, but no iOS 9 simulators set up. So I just had to open the Devices window, click the + button under Simulators, and add an iPhone 4s / iOS 9 simulator.

Comment: That's interesting.  An iOS 9 / iPhone4s device should have been created for you.  I just tried this with iOS 9.3 and got a device created.  Is it possible that you had accidentally deleted it at some point?  Note that after deleting the device, the system doesn't try to automatically recreate it for you.  The device is created the first time Xcode sees that runtime.  For example, if you used Xcode 7.3 in the past, the iOS 9.3 devices would've been created on first launch of Xcode 7.3 (and not re-created when installing the DLC with Xcode 8).

Comment: It's possible I deleted the iPhone 4s simulators when cleaning out a bunch of duplicate simulators that showed up a while ago. Or maybe Xcode 8 updated all my iOS 9 simulators to iOS 10 and discarded those that didn't support iOS 10. I just figured since Apple drops support for some older hardware and simulator versions every year, this was the latest to be dropped. I'm glad to know the option is still there just a few clicks away.

Comment: Xcode doesn't upgrade the existing devices.  It's possible for the user to do so from the command line (xcrun simctl upgrade) but that is not done by Xcode.

Comment: This is a legitimate steal, I suppose, but personally I fail to see how this differs from my answer, which was given considerably before this one. It seems to me that you've merely repeated what I said.

Answer (score 2):

iOS 10 doesn't run on any 3.5-inch devices. So you don't need to be compatible with 3.5-inch devices unless you are using a Deployment Target of iOS 9 or before. But if you are using a Deployment Target of iOS 9 or before, you can download an iOS 9 simulator and now you *can* install e.g. the iPhone 4s simulator. Here's the proof in a screenshot:

[image]

So the premise of your question is false, and your solution is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is an iPhone only app, running it on an iPad displays it in a 320x480 (3.5") window. So I can test the 3.5" screen size on an iPad!